# How to limit the normal users from accessing registry, group policy etc?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

I own the admin account of my PC running, Windows XP Pro edition. There is another Non-admin account in this system. I want to limit the administrative capabilities of this account. That is, to prevent that user from accessing registry, group policy, user accounts panel etc.

Is there anyway to do this without using third party softwares?

Comment: This sounds like a job for superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new security group and assign the user to the group. The group can then be locked down through the policy editor to limit its functionality to your needs.

Comment: But isn't there a group already for that, called "users", which non admin accounts should already belong to?

Comment: That's if they do not want to mess with the default groups, if they decide to lock things down even tighter or vary from it in any other ways.

Comment: @user48838 Can you tell me how to create such new security groups? I checked, but couldnt find any such option!

Comment: Head over to "Computer Management" and then under "Local Users and Groups" select "Groups" where you can "right-click" and create "New Group..."

Answer (score 2):

If the other user is no member of the administrators group he wont have administrative capabilities.

As example he will access te user account panel and change his own account but no anothers ones. He can access to the registriy but he cannot change any system configuration. Only its user settings.

So you should worry about it and its capabilities, he wont can change the system settings. If you as example block regedit.exe he can make the exactly same changes using another tools.

If you still want to do it can change the assigments rights of that users using the local policy editor (gpedit.msc) and the ACLs of the executable you want to change.

If you see that the user is capable for change System Settings check its group membership.

Comment: I have to agree with this. If this "non admin" account can access the registry and control panel (outside of their own settings, at least) then either they're not as "non admin" as the OP thinks or the security of the machine has been compromised somehow, and in either of those cases no advice we can give here will be valid.